# How to impletement currency checker into chatterbot response?

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am using a library named chatterbot to develop me chatbot. Assume that i am asking: *what is the currency rate between HKD and USD?* , what i to hear from chatbot is:

```
Chatbot: hkd: usd rate is 1:7
```

There are two questions need to be solved before 
 impletement this.

1. How would the chatterbot extract the two currency codes from the input?
2. How to add the rate "1:7" into the response? It's not always the rate, it could be anything select from database, then append it into the respone.

Comment: .....you didn't finish the question?

Comment: Any attempt? or just "Write teh codez"?

Comment: I press the wrong button while editing the post in mobile, dont mind it.

Comment: are you asking how the ratio is calculated/ how to input and output values?

Comment: I have breifly read the doc for chatterbot but i dont find how to solve the problems above, i find that there is a funtion named add_extra_data, is it related to the problem?

Comment: I am asking how to add addition database value into response by extract the currency code from input, the calculation part doesnt a big problem right now.

Comment: if you have code/ have tried, post your code. If you haven't, then have a try first.

Comment: I would like to try but i just don't know where to start, should i build a new logic adapter or else? I would like to have some hints.

Comment: Btw i am using a lib called chatterbot, maybe i sould include into the description as well

Comment: Hi @NgKeiYin, to accomplish this you are going to want to create a new logic adapter (http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/create-a-logic-adapter.html).